# CakePHP "action" com várias funções

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3

Eu tenho alguns pontos sobre como eu posso melhorar esta "add action" (método) em meu "controller":

Algumas descrições: No sistema o usuário pode fazer o upload de um`Product` em um único formulário, no sistema um **Produto** é composto por `Product`,ProductFeatures`e entidades ProductMedias` (e 3 tabelas diferentes em banco de dados).

Pergunta: Na mesma `action`(`add` Método do controller `Products`) eu faço várias tarefas (descritos a seguir) como seria a melhor maneira de separar conceitos e operações?

**1º:** Eu criao uma entidade `Product` e a preencho com dados do formulário e com dados customizados, em seguida, insiro na base de dados.

**2º:** Eu crio um array `ProductFeatures` (usando um método em um componente) cada posição no array é outro array com as `ProductFeatures` Key-Value

**3º:** Eu criei um array `ProductFeatures` com entidades (criadas a partir do array acima citado) e depois insiro massivamente todas no banco (usando um método em um componente).

**4º:** Envio as imagens enviadas no formulário para uma pasta adequada (usando um método em um componente).

**5º:** Eu criei um array com os dados das `Pictures` e depois e os trato para que tenham o formato correto, depois crio um array de entidades (cada entidade era uma posição do array) depois insiro massivamente todas no banco (usando um método em um componente).

```
public function add() 
{       
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        //Save Product entity
        $product = $this->Products->newEntity();
        $product = $this->Products->patchEntity($product, $this->request->data);
        $product->sub_category_id = 18;
        $product->store_id = 1;
        $productSaved = $this->Products->save($product);

        if($productSaved)
        {
            //Save ProductFeatures entities
            $featuresArray = $this->Insert->getFeatuesArray($this->request->data);
            $featuresEntities = $this->Insert->createMassFeaturesEntities($featuresArray, $productSaved['id']);
            $this->Insert->insertMassEntities($featuresEntities, 'ProductFeatures');

            //Upload pictures to folder in server
            $ROOT_PATH = dirname(ROOT) . DS;
            $PRODUCTS_IMAGES_FOLDER = $ROOT_PATH . 'ShoppingResources' . DS . 'img' . DS . $productSaved['id'];
            $imagesUploaded = $this->UploadFile->uploadFiles($PRODUCTS_IMAGES_FOLDER, $this->request->data['file']);

            //Create and Upload thumbnail to folder in server
            $outputThumb = str_replace($PRODUCTS_IMAGES_FOLDER, $ROOT_PATH . 'ShoppingResources' . DS . 'thumb', $imagesUploaded[0]['url']);
            $imageResized = $this->UploadFile->resizeImage([
                'input' => $imagesUploaded[0]['url'], 'output' => $outputThumb, 'width' => 250, 'height' => 250, 'mode' => 'stretch'
            ]);

            //Prepare image data array to be transformed into entity
            $thumbUploaded['url'] = str_replace($ROOT_PATH, 'http://localhost/PROJETOS/', $outputThumb);
            $thumbUploaded['url'] = str_replace('\\', '/', $thumbUploaded['url']);
            $thumbUploaded['media_type_id'] = 3;

            //Save Media entity (thumbnail)
            $mediaEntity = $this->Insert->createMediaEntity($thumbUploaded, $productSaved['id']);
            TableRegistry::get('Medias')->save($mediaEntity);

            //Prepare image data array to be transformed into entities
            $imagesUploaded = $this->Insert->addKeyValueToArray($imagesUploaded, 'media_type_id', 1);
            $imagesUploaded[0]['media_type_id'] = 2;
            $imagesUploaded = $this->Insert->replaceArrayValue($imagesUploaded, 'url', 'http://localhost/PROJETOS/', $ROOT_PATH);
            $imagesUploaded = $this->Insert->replaceArrayValue($imagesUploaded, 'url', '/', '\\');

            //Save Medias entities
            $mediasEntities = $this->Insert->createMassMediasEntities($imagesUploaded, $productSaved['id']);
            $this->Insert->insertMassEntities($mediasEntities, 'Medias');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Se voce criar um componente pode resolver esse problema ao inves de uma action